# gearman stop start restart command

Tags: gearman, python-gearman

What are the command to start, restart and stop `gearman`?

So far I know:

```
gearadmin --shutdown # stop
gearmand -d # I believe it is to restart. Not sure.
```

Any idea for managing `gearman`?

Comment: I checked the manual pages for `gearman`, `gearmand` and `gearadmin` and found that what you know is correct. AFAIK there is no option to `restart`. I used to kill the daemon process and start using `gearmand -d` for a `restart`. Hope it helps.

Comment: @Hussain, you can refer my answer. To restart, you should use the **gearman-job-server** command

Answer (score 7):

If you want to restart the **gearmand**, then you should use the shell script **gearman-job-server**. Type the command as `sudo service gearman-job-server restart` which STOPs and STARTs the server

----------------------    **More Information** If you need it -----------------------

I assume you have some small confusion over here. It's all because of Terminologies. The name of the application is *Gearman* which is a **Message-Queue** System.

I am answering with the assumption tha you are working with Linux OS.
When you try installing the Gearman, the application that gets installed is **gearmand** which is a Job-Server/executable file. Something like **Apache** for example.
Refer the link http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/gearmand.8.html for the command reference.

Then what's the **gearman**? **gearman** is the Client Program/Application, with which you can talk to the **gearmand**. With gearman you can run client and worker functions from  the  command      line.
Refer the link http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/gearman.1.html for the command reference.

So what's **gearadmin**? It's the tool which allows you to run Admin commands against your **gearmand**
Refer the link: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/gearadmin.1.html

Now coming to your questions about the command **gearmand**. From the shell if you run the command as **gearmand**, the Job Server starts and gets attached to your Shell Process. For ex: if you run **php** from shell the **php** runs and starts waiting for your commands right? Same way. If you want to run Gearmand as a background process, then you should run with the param as **-d** which makes it run as a **daemon**

So `gearmand -d` makes it run as Daemon. Not a restart command.

Hope this helps to answer your question and also to clarify in case if you have any confusion over the naming.

Answer (score 2):

How to STOP Gearman Server

==> gearadmin --shutdown

---

How to START Gearman Server

==> gearmand -d

Answer (score 0):

The popular answer seems to be a bit old, so if you get `Failed to restart gearman-job-server.service: Unit not found.` when trying to restart the old way, try just `sudo service gearmand restart`. That's how it seems to work on a CentOS with latest version of gearman.

For restarting the workers on the same system there seems to be a `sudo gearmanw-control restart` command avaliable.